# Rails - populating select menus for category and then subcategory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form, helper

I'm trying to make a form in my Rails 4 app which has two select tags. One for category and the other for subcategory. I want the options in subcategory to be determined by the selection made for category.

At the moment I have this form:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :irrelevant, :as => :boolean, :label =>  "Is an ethics review required or applicable to this project?"  %>

    <%= f.input :category, collection: [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], :label => "Principle",  prompt: 'select' %>

    <%= f.input :subcategory,  collection: text_for_subcategory(@category), :label => "Subcategory", prompt: 'select'  %>



    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I also have a helper with:

```
module EthicsHelper
    def text_for_subcategory(category)
      if category == 'Risk of harm'
            [ "Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
        elsif category == 'Informed consent'
            ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]
        elsif category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'
            ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
        elsif category == 'Deceptive practices' 
            ["Feasibility"] 
        else category == 'Right to withdraw'    
            ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"] 
       end
    end  

end
```

When I try this, regardless of the selection I make in the category field, the subcategory field is populated with the last attribute only (right to withdraw).

Something is wrong in what I've done above and I can't figure out what it is.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: You should use some javascript to add this functionality.

Comment: @rahul - do you have any guidance on how to go about that?

Comment: find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to the select fields:

```
<%= f.input :category, collection: [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], :label => "Principle",  prompt: 'select', class: "main_category" %>

<%= f.input :subcategory,  collection: text_for_subcategory(@category), :label => "Subcategory", prompt: 'select', class: "sub_category" %>
```

Add the below javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main_category").change(function(){
    var category = $(".main_category").val(),
        sub_category = $(".sub_category"),
        options = [],
        str = "";
    sub_category.find('option').remove();

    if(category == 'Risk of harm'){
      options = ["Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
    }
    else if(category == 'Informed consent'){
      options = ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]   
    }
    else if(category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'){
      options = ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
    }
    else if(category == 'Deceptive practices'){
      options = ["Feasibility"]
    }
    else if(category == 'Right to withdraw'){
      options = ["Right to withdraw from participation in the project"]  
    }
    if(options.length > 0){
      for(i=0;i<options.length;i++){
        str = '<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>'
        sub_category.append(str);
      }
      sub_category.val(options[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

I have not tested the code.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to set this out for me. I've tried it out and still get the same error as I encountered originally. I've tried  changing it to jQuery as well. Do I maybe need to change the 'else if' to 'elsif'?

Comment: Can you make sure that the change event is working properly by alerting a value? Like `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main_category").change(function(){ alert("Hello") });
});`

Comment: Hi - i tried but I don't get the alert. The console doesnt show an error though.

Comment: I am unable to find the issue you are facing since I don't have access to debug your code.